# unable to push notification to ios in server (GoDaddy)

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, apple-push-notifications, moonapns

I'm implementing ios push notification (c#) using moonapns.I'm using p12 certificate.It was working on my local machine but not able to push notifications after deploying in GoDaddy. It was throwing 'The given path's format is not supported.' or URI format is wrong in below line...

var push = new PushNotification(false, "certificatePath", "certificate pasword");

Comment: I'm not sure about your particular error but I've had trouble getting my GoDaddy hosted server talking to APNS which led to me abandoning GoDaddy and switching to another hosting company.

Comment: @sowjanya did you get the answer?  I am also facing the same problem and unable to resolve...